# angular5 Component unit test is broken once added ng material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am using angular material in the component template, such as

```
<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem">
        <div class='title'>
            <h3 mat-header color="primary">Loign (admin/admin or user/user)</h3>
        </div>
```

Then in my component unit test,

```
describe('LoginComponent', ()=>{

    let component:LoginComponent;
    let fixture:ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

    beforeEach(async()=>{
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations:[LoginComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

But immediately, the uni test is broken like below:

```
[ERROR ->]<mat-list-item role="listitem">
            <button (click)="login()" mat-raised-button color="primary"  "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/LoginComponent.html@23:4
    'mat-list' is not a known element:
    1. If 'mat-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'mat-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

I tried to follow the instruction into ng_module, but useless, test is still broken.

Please help to suggest how to get rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: You need to import the same modules in spec as you do the normal file. This is true for all Angular components, not just material components

Answer (score 0):

When you test any `component`, it is mandatory to import all the necessary `modules` in your test spec file, that are utilized by the `component` under test.

I would suggest you to `import` the newly added modules of `angular-material` within your test spec.